# How to plot extract igraph layout to plot with ggraph ? Example with community graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, ggraph

I would like to plot a graph with communities, in a similar way as `igraph` do but using `ggraph`.
Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(igraph)


actors <- data.table(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda","Denis","Adriana"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21,35,36),
                     gender=c("F","M","F","M","F","M","F"))
actors[,a := 1:.N]

relations <- actors[actors,on = .(a > a)][,.(from = name,to = i.name)]
relations <- relations[!is.na(from)]

relations[c(1:3,12,8,7), weight := 10]
relations[!c(1:3,12,8,7), weight := 5]
relations[c(19:21),weight := 8]
```

I would like to have:

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=F, vertices=actors )
eb <- cluster_fast_greedy(g,weights = E(g)$weight )
plot(eb,g)
```

[image]

But using `ggraph`.

I know how to plot a simple graph:

```
ggraph(g, layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_edge_fan(aes(edge_width = weight),alpha = .3) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))+
  theme_graph(foreground = 'steelblue', fg_text_colour = 'white')+
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = c("grey50","grey80"))
```

[image]

and tried to use `layout_with_fr(g,weights =  E(g)$weight)` in the `layout` argument of `ggraph`, but without success.

How can I extract the layout of the `igraph` plot to use it in `ggraph` ?